# How to check if a set of columns are a superkey of a data frame in R?

Tags: r, database, dataframe, key, primary-key

I have a data frame with a big number of observations without ID, but there are 3 columns that I believe they determine each observation/row (it is in this sense that I say that these columns are a superkey, using the terminology of data bases). How can I check this?

I know, that for only one column I could use a function as duplicated and look at frequencies, but how can I manage multiple columns and look for merged duplicated rows?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `nrow(unique(df[c("a","b","c")])) == nrow(unique(df))` ? or better : `any(duplicated(df[c("a","b","c")]))`

Comment: `duplicated` works on multiple columns too - `duplicated(df[c("a","b","c")])`

Comment: The part about "merged duplicated rows" confuses me, do you mean to test if these 3 columns are unique *unless* the full rows are duplicated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use `distinct` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
#nrow(distinct(df, x, y, z))==nrow(df)

distinct(df, x, y, z)
  x y z
1 1 1 1
2 2 4 5
```

data

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,1),y=c(1,4,1), z=c(1,5,1))
```